# My accordion doesn't open with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My accordion in 1st iteration works with ng-repeat https://jsfiddle.net/cs3rpy83/6/

but when I use expression in onclick="myFunction('{{section.id}}')" it doesn't open anymore see https://jsfiddle.net/cs3rpy83/14/ why ?

```
          <title>The W3.CSS Example</title>
  <body ng-app ng-init="app='accordion'">
<div class="w3-accordion w3-light-grey" ng-init="sections=[{'id':'section1', title:'Open Section 1'},{'id':'section2', title:'Open Section 2'}]">
<div ng-repeat= "section in sections" >
  <button onclick="myFunction('{{section.id}}')" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
    {{section.title}}
  </button>
  <div id="{{section.id}}" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>

  </div>


</div>

   </body>
```

I also have problem with tabs http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_tabulators

The difference is there is an event to pass
I tried to use $event in $scope.openCity = function(cityName) but still doesn't work right :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
<body>

<script>
var mySections = [ 
{id:'section1',name:'Norway'}, 
{id:'section2',name:'Sweden'}, 
{id:'section3',name:'Denmark'}]; 

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); 

app.controller('myController',function($scope){ 

  $scope.sections=window.mySections; 

  $scope.openCity = function(cityName) {
    var i, x, tablinks;
    x = Window.document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = Window.document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
    }
    Window.document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    $event.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
}
}); 
</script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-init="app='accordion'" ng-controller="myController">

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Active Tabs</h2>
  <p>To highlight the current tab/page the user is on, add a color class, and use JavaScript to update the active link.</p>

  <ul class="w3-navbar w3-black">
    <li ng-repeat="section in sections"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink" ng-click="openCity(section.id);">{{section.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-repeat="section in sections" id="{{section.id}}" class="w3-container w3-border city">
    <h2>{{section.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{section.name}} is the capital city of ...</p>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the function in your controller and use `ng-click`, not `onclick`

Comment: @casraf ah ok I'm absolute beginner thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must be getting the below issue in your developer console.

**Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.**

Read here for why its disallowed : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nodomevents

This specifically tells that you should use ng-click and create the fuction in your controller

```
$scope.myFunction = function(id)
{
}
```

in view

```
<button ng-click="myFunction(section.id)" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
```

Working example

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myFunction = function(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else { 
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
});
```

```css
/* W3.CSS 2.85 Jan 2017 by Jan Egil and Borge Refsnes */
html{box-sizing:border-box}*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:inherit}
/* Extract from normalize.css by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal git.io/normalize */
html{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}
audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block}progress{vertical-align:baseline}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}
a{background-color:transparent;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects}
a:active,a:hover{outline-width:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}
dfn{font-style:italic}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
sub{bottom:-0.25em}sup{top:-0.5em}figure{margin:1em 40px}
img{border-style:none}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}
hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}
button,input,select,textarea{font:inherit;margin:0}optgroup{font-weight:bold}
button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}
button,html [type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button}
button::-moz-focus-inner, [type=button]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}
button:-moz-focusring, [type=button]:-moz-focusring, [type=reset]:-moz-focusring, [type=submit]:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}
legend{color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;white-space:normal}textarea{overflow:auto}
[type=checkbox],[type=radio]{padding:0}
[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}
[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}
[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}
::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:inherit;opacity:0.54}
::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}
/* End extract */
html,body{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:1.5}html{overflow-x:hidden}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.w3-slim,.w3-wide{font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif}
h1{font-size:36px}h2{font-size:30px}h3{font-size:24px}h4{font-size:20px}h5{font-size:18px}h6{font-size:16px}
.w3-serif{font-family:"Times New Roman",Times,serif}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight:400;margin:10px 0}.w3-wide{letter-spacing:4px}
h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a{font-weight:inherit}
hr{border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee;margin:20px 0}
img{margin-bottom:-5px}a{color:inherit}
.w3-image{max-width:100%;height:auto}
.w3-table,.w3-table-all{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;display:table}
.w3-table-all{border:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-bordered tr,.w3-table-all tr{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}
.w3-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#fff}
.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-hoverable tbody tr:hover,.w3-ul.w3-hoverable li:hover{background-color:#ccc}
.w3-centered tr th,.w3-centered tr td{text-align:center}
.w3-table td,.w3-table th,.w3-table-all td,.w3-table-all th{padding:8px 8px;display:table-cell;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.w3-table th:first-child,.w3-table td:first-child,.w3-table-all th:first-child,.w3-table-all td:first-child{padding-left:16px}
.w3-btn,.w3-btn-block{border:none;display:inline-block;outline:0;padding:6px 16px;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none!important;color:#fff;background-color:#000;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap}
.w3-btn:hover,.w3-btn-block:hover,.w3-btn-floating:hover,.w3-btn-floating-large:hover{box-shadow:0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}
.w3-btn,.w3-btn-floating,.w3-btn-floating-large,.w3-closenav,.w3-opennav,.w3-btn-block{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}   
.w3-btn-floating,.w3-btn-floating-large{display:inline-block;text-align:center;color:#fff;background-color:#000;position:relative;overflow:hidden;z-index:1;padding:0;border-radius:50%;cursor:pointer;font-size:24px}
.w3-btn-floating{width:40px;height:40px;line-height:40px}.w3-btn-floating-large{width:56px;height:56px;line-height:56px}
.w3-disabled,.w3-btn:disabled,.w3-btn-floating:disabled,.w3-btn-floating-large:disabled{cursor:not-allowed;opacity:0.3}
.w3-btn.w3-disabled *,.w3-btn-block.w3-disabled,.w3-btn-floating.w3-disabled *,.w3-btn:disabled *,.w3-btn-floating:disabled *{pointer-events:none}
.w3-btn.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn-block.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn:disabled:hover,.w3-btn-floating.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn-floating:disabled:hover,
.w3-btn-floating-large.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn-floating-large:disabled:hover{box-shadow:none}
.w3-btn-group .w3-btn{float:left}.w3-btn-block{width:100%}
.w3-btn-bar .w3-btn{box-shadow:none;background-color:inherit;color:inherit;float:left}.w3-btn-bar .w3-btn:hover{background-color:#ccc}
.w3-badge,.w3-tag,.w3-sign{background-color:#000;color:#fff;display:inline-block;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;text-align:center}
.w3-badge{border-radius:50%}
ul.w3-ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0}ul.w3-ul li{padding:6px 2px 6px 16px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}ul.w3-ul li:last-child{border-bottom:none}
.w3-tooltip,.w3-display-container{position:relative}.w3-tooltip .w3-text{display:none}.w3-tooltip:hover .w3-text{display:inline-block}
.w3-navbar{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
.w3-navbar li{float:left}.w3-navbar li a,.w3-navitem,.w3-navbar li .w3-btn,.w3-navbar li .w3-input{display:block;padding:8px 16px}.w3-navbar li .w3-btn,.w3-navbar li .w3-input{border:none;outline:none;width:100%}
.w3-navbar li a:hover{color:#000;background-color:#ccc}
.w3-navbar .w3-dropdown-hover,.w3-navbar .w3-dropdown-click{position:static}
.w3-navbar .w3-dropdown-hover:hover,.w3-navbar .w3-dropdown-hover:first-child,.w3-navbar .w3-dropdown-click:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
.w3-navbar a,.w3-topnav a,.w3-sidenav a,.w3-dropdown-content a,.w3-accordion-content a,.w3-dropnav a{text-decoration:none!important}
.w3-navbar .w3-opennav.w3-right{float:right!important}.w3-topnav{padding:8px 8px}
.w3-topnav a{padding:0 8px;border-bottom:3px solid transparent;-webkit-transition:border-bottom .25s;transition:border-bottom .25s}
.w3-topnav a:hover{border-bottom:3px solid #fff}.w3-topnav .w3-dropdown-hover a{border-bottom:0}
.w3-opennav,.w3-closenav{color:inherit}.w3-opennav:hover,.w3-closenav:hover{cursor:pointer;opacity:0.8}
.w3-btn,.w3-btn-floating,.w3-dropnav a,.w3-btn-floating-large,.w3-btn-block, .w3-navbar a,.w3-sidenav a,.w3-pagination li a,.w3-hoverable tbody tr,.w3-hoverable li,
.w3-accordion-content a,.w3-dropdown-content a,.w3-dropdown-click:hover,.w3-dropdown-hover:hover,.w3-opennav,.w3-closenav,.w3-closebtn,*[class*="w3-hover-"]
{-webkit-transition:background-color .25s,color .15s,box-shadow .25s,opacity 0.25s,filter 0.25s,border 0.15s;transition:background-color .25s,color .15s,box-shadow .15s,opacity .25s,filter .25s,border .15s}
.w3-ripple:active{opacity:0.5}.w3-ripple{-webkit-transition:opacity 0s;transition:opacity 0s}
.w3-sidenav{height:100%;width:200px;background-color:#fff;position:fixed!important;z-index:1;overflow:auto}
.w3-sidenav a{padding:4px 2px 4px 16px}.w3-sidenav a:hover{background-color:#ccc}.w3-sidenav a,.w3-dropnav a{display:block}
.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-hover:hover,.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-hover:first-child,.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-click:hover,.w3-dropnav a:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-hover,.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-click {width:100%}.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-hover .w3-dropdown-content,.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-click .w3-dropdown-content{min-width:100%}
.w3-main,#main{transition:margin-left .4s}
.w3-modal{z-index:3;display:none;padding-top:100px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)}
.w3-modal-content{margin:auto;background-color:#fff;position:relative;padding:0;outline:0;width:600px}.w3-closebtn{text-decoration:none;float:right;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;color:inherit}
.w3-closebtn:hover,.w3-closebtn:focus{color:#000;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer}
.w3-pagination{display:inline-block;padding:0;margin:0}.w3-pagination li{display:inline}
.w3-pagination li a{text-decoration:none;color:#000;float:left;padding:8px 16px}
.w3-pagination li a:hover{background-color:#ccc}
.w3-input-group,.w3-group{margin-top:24px;margin-bottom:24px}
.w3-input{padding:8px;display:block;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #808080;width:100%}
.w3-label{color:#009688}.w3-input:not(:valid)~.w3-validate{color:#f44336}
.w3-select{padding:9px 0;width:100%;color:#000;border:1px solid transparent;border-bottom:1px solid #009688}
.w3-select select:focus{color:#000;border:1px solid #009688}.w3-select option[disabled]{color:#009688}
.w3-dropdown-click,.w3-dropdown-hover{position:relative;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer}
.w3-dropdown-hover:hover .w3-dropdown-content{display:block;z-index:1}
.w3-dropdown-content{cursor:auto;color:#000;background-color:#fff;display:none;position:absolute;min-width:160px;margin:0;padding:0}
.w3-dropdown-content a{padding:6px 16px;display:block}
.w3-dropdown-content a:hover{background-color:#ccc}
.w3-accordion {width:100%;cursor:pointer}
.w3-accordion-content{cursor:auto;display:none;position:relative;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
.w3-accordion-content a{padding:6px 16px;display:block}.w3-accordion-content a:hover{background-color:#ccc}
.w3-progress-container{width:100%;height:1.5em;position:relative;background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-progressbar{background-color:#757575;height:100%;position:absolute;line-height:inherit}
input[type=checkbox].w3-check,input[type=radio].w3-radio{width:24px;height:24px;position:relative;top:6px}
input[type=checkbox].w3-check:checked+.w3-validate,input[type=radio].w3-radio:checked+.w3-validate{color:#009688} 
input[type=checkbox].w3-check:disabled+.w3-validate,input[type=radio].w3-radio:disabled+.w3-validate{color:#aaa}
.w3-responsive{overflow-x:auto}
.w3-container:after,.w3-panel:after,.w3-row:after,.w3-row-padding:after,.w3-topnav:after,.w3-clear:after,.w3-btn-group:before,.w3-btn-group:after,.w3-btn-bar:before,.w3-btn-bar:after
{content:"";display:table;clear:both}
.w3-col,.w3-half,.w3-third,.w3-twothird,.w3-threequarter,.w3-quarter{float:left;width:100%}
.w3-col.s1{width:8.33333%}
.w3-col.s2{width:16.66666%}
.w3-col.s3{width:24.99999%}
.w3-col.s4{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.s5{width:41.66666%}
.w3-col.s6{width:49.99999%}
.w3-col.s7{width:58.33333%}
.w3-col.s8{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.s9{width:74.99999%}
.w3-col.s10{width:83.33333%}
.w3-col.s11{width:91.66666%}
.w3-col.s12,.w3-half,.w3-third,.w3-twothird,.w3-threequarter,.w3-quarter{width:99.99999%}
@media only screen and (min-width:601px){
.w3-col.m1{width:8.33333%}
.w3-col.m2{width:16.66666%}
.w3-col.m3,.w3-quarter{width:24.99999%}
.w3-col.m4,.w3-third{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.m5{width:41.66666%}
.w3-col.m6,.w3-half{width:49.99999%}
.w3-col.m7{width:58.33333%}
.w3-col.m8,.w3-twothird{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.m9,.w3-threequarter{width:74.99999%}
.w3-col.m10{width:83.33333%}
.w3-col.m11{width:91.66666%}
.w3-col.m12{width:99.99999%}}
@media only screen and (min-width:993px){
.w3-col.l1{width:8.33333%}
.w3-col.l2{width:16.66666%}
.w3-col.l3,.w3-quarter{width:24.99999%}
.w3-col.l4,.w3-third{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.l5{width:41.66666%}
.w3-col.l6,.w3-half{width:49.99999%}
.w3-col.l7{width:58.33333%}
.w3-col.l8,.w3-twothird{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.l9,.w3-threequarter{width:74.99999%}
.w3-col.l10{width:83.33333%}
.w3-col.l11{width:91.66666%}
.w3-col.l12{width:99.99999%}}
.w3-content{max-width:980px;margin:auto}
.w3-rest{overflow:hidden}
.w3-hide{display:none!important}.w3-show-block,.w3-show{display:block!important}.w3-show-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}
@media (max-width:600px){.w3-modal-content{margin:0 10px;width:auto!important}.w3-modal{padding-top:30px}}
@media (max-width:768px){.w3-modal-content{width:500px}.w3-modal{padding-top:50px}}
@media (min-width:993px){.w3-modal-content{width:900px}}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){.w3-topnav a{display:block}.w3-navbar li:not(.w3-opennav){float:none;width:100%!important}.w3-navbar li.w3-right{float:none!important}} 
@media screen and (max-width:600px){.w3-topnav .w3-dropdown-hover .w3-dropdown-content,.w3-navbar .w3-dropdown-click .w3-dropdown-content,.w3-navbar .w3-dropdown-hover .w3-dropdown-content{position:relative}} 
@media screen and (max-width:600px){.w3-topnav,.w3-navbar{text-align:center}}
@media (max-width:600px){.w3-hide-small{display:none!important}}
@media (max-width:992px) and (min-width:601px){.w3-hide-medium{display:none!important}}
@media (min-width:993px){.w3-hide-large{display:none!important}}
@media screen and (max-width:992px){.w3-sidenav.w3-collapse{display:none}.w3-main{margin-left:0!important;margin-right:0!important}}
@media screen and (min-width:993px){.w3-sidenav.w3-collapse{display:block!important}}
.w3-top,.w3-bottom{position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:1}.w3-top{top:0}.w3-bottom{bottom:0}
.w3-overlay{position:fixed;display:none;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z-index:2}
.w3-left{float:left!important}.w3-right{float:right!important}
.w3-tiny{font-size:10px!important}.w3-small{font-size:12px!important}
.w3-medium{font-size:15px!important}.w3-large{font-size:18px!important}
.w3-xlarge{font-size:24px!important}.w3-xxlarge{font-size:36px!important}
.w3-xxxlarge{font-size:48px!important}.w3-jumbo{font-size:64px!important}
.w3-vertical{word-break:break-all;line-height:1;text-align:center;width:0.6em}
.w3-left-align{text-align:left!important}.w3-right-align{text-align:right!important}
.w3-justify{text-align:justify!important}.w3-center{text-align:center!important}
.w3-display-topleft{position:absolute;left:0;top:0}.w3-display-topright{position:absolute;right:0;top:0}
.w3-display-bottomleft{position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0}.w3-display-bottomright{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0}
.w3-display-middle{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
.w3-display-left{position:absolute;top:50%;left:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-0%,-50%)}
.w3-display-right{position:absolute;top:50%;right:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(0%,-50%)}
.w3-display-topmiddle{position:absolute;left:50%;top:0;transform:translate(-50%,0%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%)}
.w3-display-bottommiddle{position:absolute;left:50%;bottom:0;transform:translate(-50%,0%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%)}
.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-hover{display:block}.w3-display-container:hover span.w3-display-hover{display:inline-block}.w3-display-hover{display:none}
.w3-circle{border-radius:50%!important}
.w3-round-small{border-radius:2px!important}.w3-round,.w3-round-medium{border-radius:4px!important}
.w3-round-large{border-radius:8px!important}.w3-round-xlarge{border-radius:16px!important}
.w3-round-xxlarge{border-radius:32px!important}.w3-round-jumbo{border-radius:64px!important}
.w3-border-0{border:0!important}.w3-border{border:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-top{border-top:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-bottom{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-left{border-left:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-right{border-right:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-margin{margin:16px!important}.w3-margin-0{margin:0!important}
.w3-margin-top{margin-top:16px!important}.w3-margin-bottom{margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-margin-left{margin-left:16px!important}.w3-margin-right{margin-right:16px!important}
.w3-section{margin-top:16px!important;margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-padding-tiny{padding:2px 4px!important}.w3-padding-small{padding:4px 8px!important}
.w3-padding-medium,.w3-padding,.w3-form{padding:8px 16px!important}
.w3-padding-large{padding:12px 24px!important}.w3-padding-xlarge{padding:16px 32px!important}
.w3-padding-xxlarge{padding:24px 48px!important}.w3-padding-jumbo{padding:32px 64px!important}
.w3-padding-4{padding-top:4px!important;padding-bottom:4px!important}
.w3-padding-8{padding-top:8px!important;padding-bottom:8px!important}
.w3-padding-12{padding-top:12px!important;padding-bottom:12px!important}
.w3-padding-16{padding-top:16px!important;padding-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-padding-24{padding-top:24px!important;padding-bottom:24px!important}
.w3-padding-32{padding-top:32px!important;padding-bottom:32px!important}
.w3-padding-48{padding-top:48px!important;padding-bottom:48px!important}
.w3-padding-64{padding-top:64px!important;padding-bottom:64px!important}
.w3-padding-128{padding-top:128px!important;padding-bottom:128px!important}
.w3-padding-0{padding:0!important}
.w3-padding-top{padding-top:8px!important}.w3-padding-bottom{padding-bottom:8px!important}
.w3-padding-left{padding-left:16px!important}.w3-padding-right{padding-right:16px!important}
.w3-topbar{border-top:6px solid #ccc!important}.w3-bottombar{border-bottom:6px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-leftbar{border-left:6px solid #ccc!important}.w3-rightbar{border-right:6px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-row-padding,.w3-row-padding>.w3-half,.w3-row-padding>.w3-third,.w3-row-padding>.w3-twothird,.w3-row-padding>.w3-threequarter,.w3-row-padding>.w3-quarter,.w3-row-padding>.w3-col{padding:0 8px}
.w3-spin{animation:w3-spin 2s infinite linear;-webkit-animation:w3-spin 2s infinite linear}
@-webkit-keyframes w3-spin{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(359deg);transform:rotate(359deg)}}
@keyframes w3-spin{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(359deg);transform:rotate(359deg)}}
.w3-container{padding:0.01em 16px}
.w3-panel{padding:0.01em 16px;margin-top:16px!important;margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-example{background-color:#f1f1f1;padding:0.01em 16px}
.w3-code,.w3-codespan{font-family:Consolas,"courier new";font-size:16px}
.w3-code{line-height:1.4;width:auto;background-color:#fff;padding:8px 12px;border-left:4px solid #4CAF50;word-wrap:break-word}
.w3-codespan{color:crimson;background-color:#f1f1f1;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;font-size:110%}
.w3-example,.w3-code{margin:20px 0}.w3-card{border:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-card-2,.w3-example{box-shadow:0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)!important}
.w3-card-4,.w3-hover-shadow:hover{box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)!important}
.w3-card-8{box-shadow:0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)!important}
.w3-card-12{box-shadow:0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)!important}
.w3-card-16{box-shadow:0 16px 24px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.22),0 25px 55px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.21)!important}
.w3-card-24{box-shadow:0 24px 24px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 40px 77px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.22)!important}
.w3-animate-fading{-webkit-animation:fading 10s infinite;animation:fading 10s infinite}
@-webkit-keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}
@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}
.w3-animate-opacity{-webkit-animation:opac 0.8s;animation:opac 0.8s}
@-webkit-keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
@keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-top{position:relative;-webkit-animation:animatetop 0.4s;animation:animatetop 0.4s}
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}}
@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-left{position:relative;-webkit-animation:animateleft 0.4s;animation:animateleft 0.4s}
@-webkit-keyframes animateleft{from{left:-300px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}
@keyframes animateleft{from{left:-300px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-right{position:relative;-webkit-animation:animateright 0.4s;animation:animateright 0.4s}
@-webkit-keyframes animateright{from{right:-300px;opacity:0} to{right:0;opacity:1}}
@keyframes animateright{from{right:-300px;opacity:0} to{right:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-bottom{position:relative;-webkit-animation:animatebottom 0.4s;animation:animatebottom 0.4s}
@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom{from{bottom:-300px;opacity:0} to{bottom:0px;opacity:1}}
@keyframes animatebottom{from{bottom:-300px;opacity:0} to{bottom:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-zoom {-webkit-animation:animatezoom 0.6s;animation:animatezoom 0.6s}
@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom{from{-webkit-transform:scale(0)} to{-webkit-transform:scale(1)}}
@keyframes animatezoom{from{transform:scale(0)} to{transform:scale(1)}}
.w3-animate-input{-webkit-transition:width 0.4s ease-in-out;transition:width 0.4s ease-in-out}.w3-animate-input:focus{width:100%!important}
.w3-opacity,.w3-hover-opacity:hover{opacity:0.60;filter:alpha(opacity=60);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden}
.w3-opacity-off,.w3-hover-opacity-off:hover{opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden}
.w3-opacity-max{opacity:0.25;filter:alpha(opacity=25);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden}
.w3-opacity-min{opacity:0.75;filter:alpha(opacity=75);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden}
.w3-greyscale-max,.w3-grayscale-max,.w3-hover-greyscale:hover,.w3-hover-grayscale:hover{-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);filter:grayscale(100%)}
.w3-greyscale,.w3-grayscale{-webkit-filter:grayscale(75%);filter:grayscale(75%)}
.w3-greyscale-min,.w3-grayscale-min{-webkit-filter:grayscale(50%);filter:grayscale(50%)}
.w3-sepia{-webkit-filter:sepia(75%);filter:sepia(75%)}
.w3-sepia-max,.w3-hover-sepia:hover{-webkit-filter:sepia(100%);filter:sepia(100%)}
.w3-sepia-min{-webkit-filter:sepia(50%);filter:sepia(50%)}
.w3-text-shadow{text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #444}.w3-text-shadow-white{text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #ddd}
.w3-transparent{background-color:transparent!important}
.w3-hover-none:hover{box-shadow:none!important;background-color:transparent!important}
/* Colors */
.w3-amber,.w3-hover-amber:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffc107!important}
.w3-aqua,.w3-hover-aqua:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#00ffff!important}
.w3-blue,.w3-hover-blue:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#2196F3!important}
.w3-light-blue,.w3-hover-light-blue:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#87CEEB!important}
.w3-brown,.w3-hover-brown:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#795548!important}
.w3-cyan,.w3-hover-cyan:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#00bcd4!important}
.w3-blue-grey,.w3-hover-blue-grey:hover,.w3-blue-gray,.w3-hover-blue-gray:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#607d8b!important}
.w3-green,.w3-hover-green:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#4CAF50!important}
.w3-light-green,.w3-hover-light-green:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#8bc34a!important}
.w3-indigo,.w3-hover-indigo:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#3f51b5!important}
.w3-khaki,.w3-hover-khaki:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#f0e68c!important}
.w3-lime,.w3-hover-lime:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#cddc39!important}
.w3-orange,.w3-hover-orange:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ff9800!important}
.w3-deep-orange,.w3-hover-deep-orange:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#ff5722!important}
.w3-pink,.w3-hover-pink:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#e91e63!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>The W3.CSS Example</title>
  <body ng-app ="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="app='accordion'">
<div class="w3-accordion w3-light-grey" ng-init="sections=[{'id':'section1', title:'Open Section 1'},{'id':'section2', title:'Open Section 2'}]">
<div ng-repeat= "section in sections" >
  <button ng-click="myFunction(section.id)" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
    {{section.title}}
  </button>
  <div id="{{section.id}}" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  

</div>

   </body>
```

Comment: @user310291 you are mixing javascript syntax with angular, I will suggest to do things with angular way only , check the plunker for your example https://plnkr.co/edit/CsyU818XPWVVgNTseUE5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @Deep will look at it